# How do I get TTM_POPUP to not fade out instantly and then come back?

Tags: c, winapi, tooltip, comctl32

I've decided that th easiest way to handle tooltips in my table control is to handle the initial delay myself, create the tooltip dynamically, and then destroy it when it's not needed anymore. My problem is that when I use `TTM_POPUP` to show the tooltip, it fades out instantly and comes back again some time later. I'd rather have it fade in and stay there once.

My hypothesis is that the tooltip is handling the tooltip delay itself, and fading the existing tip out and back in. I'm not sure what to do about that. Should I just set the delay time to 0 and expect it to work (without worrying about `TTM_POPUP` at all)? Or is there a better way? Or am I wrong?

The program below demonstrates what's going on. Simply hover the mouse over the window and you should see it.

Tested on Windows XP and Windows 7. This is strictly with Common Controls 6.

**EDIT** Okay, I tried adding a `TTM_SETDELAYTIME` to set the initial time to 0 (not reflected in the program below). It didn't work. If I keep the `TTM_POPUP` afterward, it just fades out even faster than usual (which proves my hypothesis, maybe). If I remove the `TTM_POPUP`, it doesn't show up until I move the mouse anyway. So is there something else I can do to just get my tooltip to pop up?

Thanks!

```
// 5 april 2015
// based on wintooltipsubclasstest.c 31 march-2 april 2015
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS
#define CINTERFACE
// get Windows version right; right now Windows XP
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0501       /* according to Microsoft's winperf.h */
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0600            /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x05010000    /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void die(char *why)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error %s: %I32u\n", why, GetLastError());
    abort();
}

HWND tooltip = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInstance;

void makeTooltip(HWND hwnd)
{
    TOOLINFOW ti;

    tooltip = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
        TOOLTIPS_CLASSW, L"",
        WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX,
        0, 0,
        0, 0,
        hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (tooltip == NULL)
        die("creating tooltip");

    ZeroMemory(&ti, sizeof (TOOLINFOW));
    ti.cbSize = TTTOOLINFOW_V2_SIZE;
    ti.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS | TTF_TRANSPARENT;
    ti.hwnd = hwnd;
    ti.uId = (UINT_PTR) hwnd;
    ti.hinst = hInstance;
    ti.lpszText = L"this is a tooltip! wow!";
    if (SendMessageW(tooltip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) (&ti)) == FALSE)
        die("setting up tooltip");
}

LPARAM last = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        // cheap way of testing for hovers
        if (lParam != last)
            SetTimer(hwnd, 1, GetDoubleClickTime(), NULL);
        last = lParam;
        break;
    case WM_TIMER:
        if (wParam != 1)
            break;
        KillTimer(hwnd, 1);
        makeTooltip(hwnd);
        SendMessage(tooltip, TTM_POPUP, 0, 0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void initCommonControls(BOOL);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BOOL comctl5;
    WNDCLASSW wc;
    HWND mainwin;
    MSG msg;

    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    comctl5 = FALSE;
    if (argc > 1)
        comctl5 = strcmp(argv[1], "comctl5") == 0;
    initCommonControls(comctl5);

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mainwin";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (RegisterClassW(&wc) == 0)
        die("registering main window class");

    mainwin = CreateWindowExW(0,
        L"mainwin", L"Main Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if (mainwin == NULL)
        die("creating main window");

    ShowWindow(mainwin, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(mainwin);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

// MSDN doesn't list a constant that only includes tooltips but says this and a few others do
#define wantedICCClasses (ICC_BAR_CLASSES)

static ULONG_PTR comctlManifestCookie;
static HMODULE comctl32;

// note that this is an 8-bit character string we're writing; see the encoding clause
static const char manifest[] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<assembly xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1\" manifestVersion=\"1.0\">\n<assemblyIdentity\n    version=\"1.0.0.0\"\n    processorArchitecture=\"*\"\n    name=\"CompanyName.ProductName.YourApplication\"\n    type=\"win32\"\n/>\n<description>Your application description here.</description>\n<dependency>\n    <dependentAssembly>\n        <assemblyIdentity\n            type=\"win32\"\n            name=\"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\"\n            version=\"6.0.0.0\"\n            processorArchitecture=\"*\"\n            publicKeyToken=\"6595b64144ccf1df\"\n            language=\"*\"\n        />\n    </dependentAssembly>\n</dependency>\n</assembly>\n";

void initCommonControls(BOOL comctl5)
{
    WCHAR temppath[MAX_PATH + 1];
    WCHAR filename[MAX_PATH + 1];
    HANDLE file;
    DWORD nExpected, nGot;
    ACTCTX actctx;
    HANDLE ac;
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc;
    FARPROC f;
    // this is listed as WINAPI in both Microsoft's and MinGW's headers, but not on MSDN for some reason
    BOOL (*WINAPI ficc)(const LPINITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);

    if (!comctl5) {
        if (GetTempPathW(MAX_PATH + 1, temppath) == 0)
            die("getting temporary path for writing manifest file");
        if (GetTempFileNameW(temppath, L"manifest", 0, filename) == 0)
            die("getting temporary filename for writing manifest file");
        file = CreateFileW(filename, GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,          // don't share while writing
            NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (file == NULL)
            die("creating manifest file");
        nExpected = (sizeof manifest / sizeof manifest[0]) - 1;     // - 1 to omit the terminating null character)
        if (WriteFile(file, manifest, nExpected, &nGot, NULL) == 0)
            die("writing manifest file");
        if (nGot != nExpected)
            die("short write to manifest file");
        if (CloseHandle(file) == 0)
            die("closing manifest file (this IS an error here because not doing so will prevent Windows from being able to use the manifest file in an activation context)");

        ZeroMemory(&actctx, sizeof (ACTCTX));
        actctx.cbSize = sizeof (ACTCTX);
        actctx.dwFlags = ACTCTX_FLAG_SET_PROCESS_DEFAULT;
        actctx.lpSource = filename;
        ac = CreateActCtx(&actctx);
        if (ac == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            die("creating activation context for synthesized manifest file");
        if (ActivateActCtx(ac, &comctlManifestCookie) == FALSE)
            die("activating activation context for synthesized manifest file");
    }

    ZeroMemory(&icc, sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX));
    icc.dwSize = sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icc.dwICC = wantedICCClasses;

    comctl32 = LoadLibraryW(L"comctl32.dll");
    if (comctl32 == NULL)
        die("loading comctl32.dll");
    f = GetProcAddress(comctl32, "InitCommonControlsEx");
    if (f == NULL)
        die("loading InitCommonControlsEx()");
    ficc = (BOOL (*WINAPI)(const LPINITCOMMONCONTROLSEX)) f;
    if ((*ficc)(&icc) == FALSE)
        die("initializing Common Controls (comctl32.dll)");
}
```